# Python Question for Algorithm Engineering Course

Tags: python, algorithm

I am having trouble with a homework question from my algorithm engineering course and want some advice on how to tackle it.

Here is the question:
. Each of the following snippets of pseudocode fails to live up to all of the clarity, correctness,
and termination requirements of algorithms. In each case, describe the problem, and then
rewrite the pseudocode as a proper algorithm. Hint: consult the checklist in section 2.3.

I have tried looking at the check list in section 2.3.

For example here are some of the requirements:

1. I/O
2. undefined variables
3. variable meanings
4. defined return values

(a)

```
def contains(S):  
  for x in S :  
     if x == 0 :   
       return True  
   else:  
       return False
```

I do not expect an answer to my homework question. I am really looking for some more resources and guidance on how to answer this question because I do not see anything wrong with the pseudocode at this point.

Comment: *"I am really looking for some more resources and guidance"* - that's not what SO is here to provide, please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: @shash678 I did not fix the indentation. I just moved the code away from surrounding text so it would be formatted correctly. The indentation is still broken.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other resources... but maybe a couple questions that can help analyze this kind of question.  I don't know what they mean by I/O without more context, but for the other three 'requirements'

Undefined Variables:

- Are there any variables used that haven't been assigned a value?

Variable Meaning:

- What does this algorithm do?
- What is(are) the parameter(s) to this method?
- What do the local variables hold?

Defined Return Values:

- Is there any path through this function that leaves my return value unassigned?